# algebraic or combinatorial proof to an identity of Stirling numbers of the first kind

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinatorial-proofs, stirling-numbers

We denote Stirling numbers of the first kind as $s(n,m)$ counting the ways we can put $n$ people in $m$ cycles.

What is a combinatorial/algebraic proof to this identity?

$$s(n+1,m+1)=\sum_k{s(n,k). ^kC_m}$$

Which $^kC_m$ is $ k$ choose $m$.

I tried to say like this: we put one person away so we have $n$ people left. Then we put them around $k\geq m$ cycles. Then we choose $m$ of these cycles and hold them as they are. Then merge the people on other cycles and the person we picked at the beginning. But I can't explain this merging. Maybe my approach isn't true from the beginning. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: See e.g. [Where can I find a proof, that $s(n+1,k+1) = \sum_{i = 0}^{n} \binom{i}{k}s(n,i)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3028166/where-can-i-find-a-proof-that-sn1-k1-sum-i-0n-binomiksn-i) or [Stirling number of the first kind: Proof of Recursion formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/34156/stirling-number-of-the-first-kind-proof-of-recursion-formula).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Stirling number of the first kind: Proof of Recursion formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/34156/stirling-number-of-the-first-kind-proof-of-recursion-formula)